# Asignar variables a partir de cadena introducida por teclado en C

Tags: c, variables

Necesito lograr lo siguiente:

El usuario introducirá el siguiente comando por teclado: **primos entrada.txt -t -n 5**

Donde **primos** es el ejercicio, **entrada.txt** un archivo que contiene números, **-t** para indicar que se crearán hilos, y **-n** para indicar cuantos hilos. Almacenar cada dato de estos en una variable independiente es lo que necesito, y he escrito el siguiente código, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char cadena [100];
    printf ("\nLa instrucción, debe tener el siguiente formato:\n");
    printf("primos entrada.txt [-t | -p] [-n N] -> ");
    /* primos entrada.txt -t -n N */
    fgets (cadena, 100, stdin);

    //
    int longitud = strlen(cadena) - 1;
    char primos[6];
    char entradaTXT[10];
    char tipo[2];
    char cantidad[2];
    char n[2];
    // Ejercicio Primos
    fflush(stdin);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        primos[i] = cadena[i];
    }

    // entrada.txt
    fflush(stdin);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 8; i < 18; i++) {
        entradaTXT[j] = cadena[i];
        j++;
    }
    // Tipo (Hilos o procesos)
    fflush(stdin);
    j = 0;
    for(int i = 20; i < 21; i++) {
        tipo[j] = cadena[i];
        j++;
    }
    // Cantidad de hilos o procesos
    fflush(stdin);
    j = 0;
    for(int i = 23; i < 24; i++) {
        cantidad[j] = cadena[i];
        j++;
    }
    //printf("\n%s",&primos[6]);
    printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",&primos[6],&entradaTXT[10],&tipo[10]);
    fflush(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

El resultado que obtengo al compilar y ejecutar es el siguiente:

[image: Captura del resultado, tras ejecutar el código]

Al parecer se están almacenando todas las variables en una sola cadena, pero no entiendo el por qué, alguien podría darme una mano?

Answer (score 1):

> El usuario introducirá el siguiente comando por teclado: primos entrada.txt -t -n 5

Lo que te están diciendo ahí es que el programa se está ejecutando con ciertos argumentos. Es decir, tu programa se va a llamar `primos` y, en vez de ejecutarl simplemente como `.\primos` se va a ejecutar con ciertos parámetros `.\primos entrada.txt [-t -n 5]`. Los parámetros que he puesto entre corchetes entiendo que son opcionales, es decir, si el programa se arranca sin `-t` entonces se ejecutará todo en un único hilo.

Bien, para leer estos parámetros de entrada tienes que modificar tu main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
}
```

donde:

- `argc`: indica el número de parámetros de entrada (mínimo 1).
- `argv`: un array con `argc` parámetros (en formato texto). Recuerda que `argv[0]` **siempre** indica el nombre del ejecutable.

Así, podrías tener lo siguiente:

- `argv[0]`: nombre del ejecutable
- `argv[1] == "-t"`
- `argv[2] == "-n"`
- `argv[3] == "5"`-> nota que el 5 está en caracteres no en dígitos numéricos

No profundizo más sobre el tema porque entiendo que el trabajarte la lectura de esos parámetros es parte primordial del ejercicio.

Comment: Es justamente lo que necesitaba, no tenía conocimiento de que esto podía hacerse, podrías indicarme el nombre de ese tópico para investigar más acerca del tema @eferion ?